# How can I clear cache of my app automatically after 1 hr

Tags: android, caching

I am working on a story application. In this application we download JSON data from the server and these data should be saved in cache.
I stored data in cache but I want delete this cache after particular time limit.

My code for adding data in cache is as follows:

```
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl")); 
String tetsing = jsonObject_one.toString(); 
out.writeObject( tetsing );
```

Comment: Use AlarmManager set alarm and once alarm will occur, delete your cache.

Comment: You should specify how you save the data on the cache.

Comment: ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"));
      String tetsing = jsonObject_one.toString();
      out.writeObject( tetsing );                                       I followed this approach for store data in cache

Answer (score 1):

When you do your call to server, receive your callback and add your entities in your local DB, you can save in shared preferences a long with current system milliseconds:

```
long cacheTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Everytime you open the Activity that needs to call the server, before doing the request, check the time in shared preferences:

```
if(timeInSharedPreference < System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000 * 60 * 60) {
    // do the request
    // update DB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//Repeat the alarm for every 1 hour and attach the receiver to be called   after 1 hr interval
    private void repeatAlarm() {
        Date when = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            Intent someIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class); // intent to be launched
            // note this could be getActivity if you want to launch an activity
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, // id, optional
                    someIntent, // intent to launch
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); // PendintIntent flag
            AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //You need to create your own receiver to be called after particular interval of time
    //TODO: Don't forget to declare it in manifest
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            deleteCache(context);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    //TODO: Add the "android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" permission in your manifest
    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can we create cache again after 1 hr continuously?